# How can I hook functionality to the "go to line"-command in Vim?

Tags: vim

I just got the idea that I wanted to make it so that Vim centered around a line when I jump to it.

Is there a way to make `zz` be executed automatically after I have called the colon command followed by only digits (`:175` for example)?

Comment: I'd use normal mode only `175Gzz`

Comment: You can actually just use `175zz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override normal-mode commands (like `[N]G`) with `:nnoremap`, but there's no hook for *Ex commands* (like the peculiar `:[N]`). Your only options are a hook on the `CursorMoved` event:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved * normal! zz
```

but that would affect **all** jumps, or a custom command, e.g. `:[N]J`, but that's even more typing.

Best re-teach yourself to use `G` (it's shorter, too!) and use this mapping:

```
:nnoremap <expr> G (v:count ? 'Gzz' : 'G')
```

Comment: Sweet! I've only used G to go to the end of the document before. Thanks a lot! :)